# What's the difference between "manch" and "viel"?

Tags: word-choice

They both mean "many," right? But are they used in different contexts or ways?

The question arises from my German translation of the following song.

http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/t/tommy_edwards/its_all_in_the_game.html

I came up with:

> Es gibt die Träne soviel, 
>   Aber daß ist das Spiel.
>   Alle in dem wunderbaren Liebespiel.

for

> "Many a tear has to fall,
>   But it's in the game.
>   All in the wonderful game that we know as love.

Another version begins:

Manche Traene fallen mußen... and it doesn't go as smoothly.

What are the pros and cons of using "viel" and "manch" in this context (and others)?

Comment: By the way, *Liebesspiel* is quite specific for *physical love*, and I'm not quite sure this is what *the game we know as love* is supposed to express here... (or is it really?)

Comment: Sure, you can translate *many* with *viel* but the collocated *many a* is often *manch eine(r)*. *Manch* and *viel* are quite different and so is *many* and *many a* as well. My suggestion (without knowing the song and what is is about) : *Manch eine Träne musste fließen, aber das gehört zum Spiel. Alles zu dem wundervollen Spiel, das wir als Liebe bezeichnen.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [Manche](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/manche)

The usual translations for *"manche"* would be *"some"*.

Though old-fashioned it may also be used with the meaning of *"many"*, or *"many a"*, especially in a poetical context. To better reflect this we may use it in conjunction with *"so"*:

> **So manche** Träne musste fließen [...]

Note that it is better to use the **singular** for *tears* when using *"manche"*.

*Sidenote:* Tears *"fließen"* rather than *"fallen"*.

Answer (score 5):

*Viel* can mean different things, like *much*, *a lot*, etc.

> Much ado about nothing
>   Viel Lärm um nichts

*Manch* is more like *some*:

> Some have tried
>   Mancher hat es schon probiert

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to translate it by "some", instead of "many". It's meaning is mostly equivalent to "einige", followed by a plural, but there the word might be used both with a singular or a plural noun for stylistic reasons.

- Einige Tränen müssen fließen
- Manche Tränen müssen fließen
- Manche Träne muss fließen
- Manch eine Träne muss fließen
- So einige Tränen müssen fließen
- So manche Tränen müssen fließen
- So manche Träne muss fließen
- So manch eine Träne muss fließen

These all mean the same, but while the first one is very plain, the last one can be regarded as poetic. I believe that it might make sense to regard 'manch', 'manch eine' (followed by a singular) and the versions with preceeding 'so' as distinct families of article words.